# Why is "-ber" the suffix of the last four months of the year?

Tags: suffixes, latin, dates

- Septem**ber**
- Octo**ber**
- Novem**ber**
- Decem**ber**

Presumably something Latin, but my (admittedly brief) search sees only mention of the number-based root words.

More specifically, what does "-ber" mean?

Comment: The French have _-bre_ as the suffix. I'm guessing Latin.

Comment: Because they're cold and make you go "Brrr!"

Comment: @HotLicks feb-brrr-ary

Comment: @HotLicks not where I live. (But no shoveling snow, either...)

Comment: @Hot September?

Comment: @Randal'Thor the average low in September in 72F.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Depends on where you live.  Here in Tropical Southern Minnesota the temp dips down to 40 and struggles to get up to 65.

Comment: Also now misnamed - Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec for 9th 10th 11th and 12th months?! Maybe 'ber' should mean ' two out of kilter'..?

Comment: @Tim the first month used to be March.

Comment: @RonJohn - I always thought that the Caesers - Julius and Augustus, put two months with their own names in, which shifted everything up by two. And where did January and febrary come from - I know Janus the god looked backwards and forwards.

Comment: February was originally the last month of the year until around 450 B.C. - hence the reason it's shorter by a few days, and the reason it's the one that gets affected by leap years.  The months all used to be shorter and they used to just stick a [whole other month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedonius) in there every now and then to get back on track.

Comment: The summer and winter solstice shift slightly. It is conceivable that the vernal equinox once lay in December/January. Counting shifted slightly (due to this) too. Vernal equinox in February?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I heard that February got short-changed because days were stolen from it and given to July and August, when those months were renamed in honor of the emperors.

Comment: Are you asking why the suffix applies to the last four months in the sense of it being associated with their position in the calendar, or just why any month name would have that suffix?

Comment: @nnnnnn this: "or just why any month name would have that suffix".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/December?ref=etymonline_crossreference):

> The -ber in four Latin month names is probably from -bris, an adjectival suffix. Tucker thinks that the first five months were named for their positions in the agricultural cycle, and "after the gathering in of the crops, the months were merely numbered."
>
> > If the word contains an element related to mensis, we must assume a **decemo-membris* (from **-mensris*). October must then be by analogy from a false division *Sep-tem-ber* &c. Perhaps, however, from **de-cem(o)-mr-is*, i.e. "forming the tenth part or division," from **mer-* ..., while October = **octuo-mr-is.* [T.G. Tucker, "Etymological Dictionary of Latin"]

Comment: As far as I know in Roman times the year started with March, making January and February the last months (so 'Sept'ember was the 7th month, 'Octo'ber the 8th and so on). Following Tucker's reasoning, January and February should have been numbered but obviously they aren't, so I think his reasoning is not the full explanation.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven When the months originally got their names in the Roman calendar, the year began with March, and there were only ten named months.  What we now call January and February were just an un-named block of days not assigned to any month, and the months following Junius (June) were Quintilis and Sextilis (for the numbers five and six).  The Julian calendar reform moved the beginning of the year and renamed Quintilis to "Julius".  Soon after, Sextilis was renamed "Augustus".  In each case, the months were expanded to 31 days at the expense of February.

Comment: @MontyHarder I stand corrected. Today I learned that the history of the Roman calendar is a lot more complex than I thought.

Comment: That's just so odd that a civilization would name 10 out of 12 months and just be OK with the fact there was this yearly period of time with no name.

Comment: This is a hypothesis, not an answer. I might as well submit that *-ber* is analog to *duonos*/*bonus*, *duellum*/*bellum*, *duo*/*bi*, thus akin to \*deH- "part" (+ some nomiative *-r*), which only makes sense if this were akin to \*dwo- "two" (the *b* is thought to be due to the labial *w*, surely in some dialect), which would be motivated by *to make two* ~ *to half, to split, to part*. Incidentally, I think, that's pretty much the meaning of *mensis* (cp. *measure*, *mensur*, further *to mean, to decide*). Also compare *to break*.

Comment: [\*mer-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/mer-) is otherwise linked to 1. "disappear" (cp "to murk sb."?); 2. *mare* "sea" (viz *titular seas*? hardly), 3. \*m-r-* "bad, vaine" (eg. allegedly Persian *fara-mushi* "to forget"). Otherwise I don't know what Tucker refers to, however compare 1. *to part*; 2. *tide* ~ Ger *Zeit* "time"; 3. *to miss*, \*mey- "to change", Ger *vermissen* (fig. "to have forgotten sth.")

Comment: @JPhi1618 The idea of having days off any month was retaken after the French Revolution when they invented and used a calendar with 12 months of 30 days each, with 5 or 6 complementary days. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_calendar#Months

Comment: The answer being directly accessible from the reference Etymon makes this question off-topic.

Answer (score -2):

Romans spoke Latin. Their first 10 numbers were: Unus, Duo, Tres, Quattuor, Quinque, Sex, Septem, Octo, Novem, and Decem.
The Latin ber translates to per. This could be referencing a ratio. So Septem ber would be the seventh part of a ten month year of campaigning.

Their calender would then be Unusber, Duober, Tresber, Quattuorber, Quinqueber, Sexber, September, October, November, December for the 10 months they would be able to engage in war. Two months were added to the end of their calendar: January and February for the period where they wouldn't go to war.

Their calendar began with Unusber (named March) as their focus was on being able to conquer the known world.

January was named for the Roman god Janus, protector of gates and doorways. Janus is depicted with two faces, one looking into the past, the other into the future. January was meant to be a time when the military campaigns ceased and there time for peace and reflection.

February comes from the Latin word februa, “to cleanse.” The Roman calendar month of Februarius was named for Februalia, a festival of purification and atonement that took place during this period.

Unus ber was called March, named for the Roman god of war, Mars. This was the time of year to resume military campaigns that had been interrupted by winter. The word march is a play on this relationship, as one would march off to battle. March was also a time of many festivals, presumably in preparation for the campaigning season.

Duo ber became April, from the Latin word aperio, “to open (bud),” because plants begin to grow in this month. In essence, this month was viewed as spring’s renewal.

Tresber was named May for the Roman goddess Maia, who oversaw the growth of plants. Also from the Latin word maiores, “elders,” who were celebrated during this month. Maia was considered a nurturer and an earth goddess, which may explain the connection with this springtime month.

Quattuor ber became June, named for the Roman goddess Juno, patroness of marriage and the well-being of women. Also from the Latin word juvenis, “young people.”

Quinqueber became July, named to honor Roman dictator Julius Caesar (100 B.C.– 44 B.C.) after his death. In 46 B.C., Julius Caesar made one of his greatest contributions to history: With the help of Sosigenes, he developed the Julian calendar, the precursor to the Gregorian calendar we use today.

Lastly, Sex ber became August, named to honor the first Roman emperor (and grandnephew of Julius Caesar), Augustus Caesar (63 B.C.– A.D. 14). Augustus (the first Roman emperor) comes from the Latin word “augustus,” meaning venerable, noble, and majestic.
The Gregorian Calendar then shifted the month of January to the beginning of the Year, which was fitting, due to Janus being the god of beginnings.

Comment: There is a lot of interesting information, but after the first few sentences it's not relevant to the question.